# How to get null value when no data matched in condition in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like follows

```
col1 col2 name
a    null record1
null b    record2
null null record3
```

and when I execute following query, I will get `col1=a` or `col2=b`

```
select * 
from table 
where col1 = 'a' or col2 = 'b'
```

```
col1 col2 name
a    null record1
null b    record2
```

But when I select value which is not exists col1 and col2, I would like to get `record3` which doesn't have values and fill with `null`

For example,when I execute like follows,

```
select * 
from table 
where col1 = 'c' 
or col2 = 'd'
-- or certain condition here
```

I would like to get following records. because `col1=c` or `col2=d` couldn't find

```
col1 col2 name
null null record3
```

Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use null safe equality checks with `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'c' OR col2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'd';
```

Comment: thank you for comment, I encountered following error ,,`ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <=> unknown`  is it supported in postgres 13.6(my version) ? Thanks

Comment: Please check the updated answer.